# Access classes from other module

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I have an minecraft forge workspace that is made by gradle, I have an project in which I have an module with the mod I'm working on and one module with my library mod, I want to somehow access classes from my library mod from the other module, I imported modules by using their build.gradle and now I have 2 different modules but I can't access one module from another one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a dependency from the working module on the library module. If this is a multi-module Gradle build where both projects are modules, you can simply add a `project(':library')` dependency. If those are separate Gradle builds, you need to add a normal dependency like `'your.group:library-module:1.0'` and then either install the library module to some repository like the local maven repository with the `mavenPublish` plugin to be able to use it from the working module, or use a composite build to replace the dependency by the automatically built result of the library module. For more information on how to do either, you should read the Gradle Userguide.

Comment: Looks like that did it I got into module settings got into its dependencies and added the other module as compile

Comment: If you only do it in IJ your build will not work from Gradle.